# Angular ngAfterViewInit() not finding DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to target a menu item element in my navigation that has an active class in order to do some custom animations.

```
export class NavComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('container', { static: true }) container: ElementRef

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const activeEl = this.container.nativeElement.querySelector('.active')
        console.log(activeEl)
    }
}
```

This returns `null` when I am expecting something like `<a class="active">Home</a>`. However if I wrap the querySelector in a setTimeout function I get the correct result.

This made me think `ngAfterViewInit()` was firing before the router was finished its events.

I wrote a function to subscribe to the router events however it has the same result

```
constructor(private route: Router) {
    this.routeEvent(this.route)
}

routeEvent(router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.container.nativeElement.querySelector('.active')
        }
    })
}
```

This will also return null but if I wrap this in a setTimeout as well if works.

My links look like this

```
<nav #container>
    <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/link1']" routerLinkActive="active">Link1</a>
    <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/link2']" routerLinkActive="active">Link2</a>
    <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/link3']" routerLinkActive="active">Link3</a>
    <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/link4']" routerLinkActive="active">Link4</a>
</nav>
```

I am just trying to get the DOM element of the link with the active class at the end of some sort of lifecycle method or observable event. Am I missing something or am I stuck with setTimeouts and race conditions?

Comment: `<a #container class="link" [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `static:false`:

```
@ViewChild('container', { static: false }) container: ElementRef
```

[As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration#how-do-i-choose-which-static-flag-value-to-use-true-or-false)

> In the official API docs, we have always recommended retrieving query
>   results in `ngAfterViewInit` for view queries and `ngAfterContentInit` for
>   content queries. This is because by the time those lifecycle hooks
>   run, change detection has completed for the relevant nodes and we can
>   guarantee that we have collected all the possible query results.
>   Most applications will want to use `{static: false}` for the same
>   reason. This setting will ensure query matches that are dependent on
>   binding resolution (e.g. results inside `*ngIfs` or `*ngFor's`) will be
>   found by the query.